# Сообщение в Docker Desktop «Docker Engine stopped» после установки в (Kali Linux)

Tags: linux, docker, kali-linux

При первом запуске Docker Desktop появилась надпись : Docker engine stopped
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPblK.png)